# How do I set up a web form to support iOS 8 credit card scanning in mobile safari?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, ios8, ocr, credit-card

One of the features of iOS 8 is the ability to use the phone's camera to scan credit cards and have the number automatically entered into inputs in Safari. See here: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/scan-your-credit-card-instead-of-keying-in-number-for-purchases-in-ios-8/

However, while I've confirmed it works for amazon.com's mobile site, it doesn't work for smaller retailers. What do those retailers need to do to get it working for their sites?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have a website up and the card number cannot be scanned.

Answer (score 6):

There is answer to your question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925195/4079317

1. You have to use correct id for input field. Example:

   id="credit-card-number"
2. Site have to be accessed over HTTPS and need to have valid certificate.

Answer (score 5):

When we set the field `name`, `id`, `label` and `autocomplete` attributes in a HTML form, it will autocomplete those fields, not only to scan a credit card but for other types of forms too. (Like checkout form).

In this scenarios:

1. When a form is submitted **some browsers** will store these values with their **input names** it will offer autocomplete those fields next time when the user comes across a form with the same names.
2. **Some other browsers** will scan for **autocomplete field** values, and

(3) some others scan input labels and input names.

And when a card is scanned browser just need to know where to put those values correctly.

Now look at the `autocomplete` for HTML5.

Earlier `autocomplete` had only `on` and `off` values only. Now they have a ton including `cc-name` (Card name), `cc-number`, `cc-exp`, `cc-csc` (Security number - CVV) etc. (full list [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#inappropriate-for-the-control))

How we apply this:

```
<label>Credit card number: 
  <input type=text autocomplete="cc-number">
</label>
```

In general it's like:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="[section-](optional) [shipping|billing](optional) 
[home|work|mobile|fax|pager](optional) [autofill field name]">
```

ex:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" autocomplete="section-red shipping mobile tel">
```

Here:

```
section-red : wrapping as a section. (named red)
shipping : shopping/billing
mobile   : home|work|mobile|fax|pager (For telephone)
tel      : [Tokens][2]
```

When we code it like these browser know exactly what kind of value should be populated in that field. But browser like safari need `name` or `id` or `label` values should be set right.

### Support so far for `autocomplete`, `id` and `name` attributes for auto completing values.

```
Browse  Ver OS              ID      Name    Autocomplete
Chrome  50  OS X 10.11.4    No      Yes     Yes
Opera   35  OS X 10.11.4    No      Yes     Yes
Firefox 46  OS X 10.11.4    Yes     Yes     No
Edge    25  Windows 10      No      Yes     No
Safari  9.1 OS X 10.11.4    Partial Partial Partial
Safari  9   iOS  9.3.1      Partial Partial Partial
```

Safari has no documentation for this. Here's the [blog](http://blog.cloudfour.com/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/) I refereed.