# How to disable "Scan Credit Card" feature on iOS 8 Safari?

Tags: html, safari, ios8

Recently, Safari on iOS 8 has introduced a new feature "Scan Credit Card" on form fields it detects as a credit card input. However, I can't find any documentation on how this feature works, or more importantly, how to disable this. I DON'T want this displayed on my form, but I don't see any way to disable it.

Has anyone figured out how to disable this "feature"?

Comment: Not sure.. But i guess, Safari will invoke the scanner, if it get the name or class of an element withe the name "cardName","CardNumber" and etc.Try to change the element name and/or type and check whether it works or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163891/when-is-the-scan-credit-card-option-available-on-ios8-safari has some helpful information