# Disable/ Hide Scan Credit Card option on iOS8 Safari?

Tags: ios, html, css, ipad, safari

In Safari on iOS if I open my login page it shows "Scan Credit Card", how can I hide this as this is not relevant for the username or password text box.

I tried to find answer here [How to disable "Scan Credit Card" feature on iOS 8 Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023276/how-to-disable-scan-credit-card-feature-on-ios-8-safari)  but no one has replied to it yet. Image is shown below as reference:
[image]