# Is the Scan Credit Card option available on the WebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, credit-card, sfsafariviewcontroller

The new iOS8 Scan Credit Card option is great on Safari.

Has someone managed to make it work inside a WebView for a web app?

I am using a valid SSL certificate, and I am using the correct ID for input filed as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925195/3949713

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When Scan Credit Card option is available on iOS8 Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163891/when-scan-credit-card-option-is-available-on-ios8-safari)

Comment: No I need this working for the WebView inside an app, not in Safari.

Comment: @SamTso Have you found any solution or workaround for this??

Comment: @HimanshuGarg haven't got a solution, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

No, this option is not available in neither `UIWebView` nor `WKWebView`.

Your best bet is to use `SFSafariViewController` instead. The reason it works there is because it runs in a separate process, to prevent your app from getting access to this security-relevant information.