# iOS credit card autofill persists on drop down inputs

Tags: html, ios, credit-card

I have come across a bug on a website I am working on with the credit card autofill iOS offers. I cannot offer a working example of this is as it requires a genuine SSL certificate in order for the autofill to appear on an iOS keyboard however I can actually get this to occur on Amazon's checkout too.

In essence the issue is that after having been offered to autofill having focused on any [credit card enabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163891/when-scan-credit-card-option-is-available-on-ios8-safari) it looks like all drop down input keyboards will also offer to autofill your credit card.

This happens even after a page refresh and even across different domains. All dropdowns will have `autofill credit card` up until a non credit card plain text input has been focused on.

Below is a simplified version of the problem:

```
<input id="cardNumber"/> <!-- <-- Activates autofill -->
<select id="normalSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<input id="normalInput"/>
```

1. Touch `#cardNumber` and be offered to autofill on the keyboard
2. Touch `#normalSelect` (or any non-credit card drop down) and still be offered to autofill incorrectly

(You can optionally refresh the site at this point or even navigate to another domain with non credit card enabling drop downs and try them to see if they offer autofill incorrectly too. It doesn't even have to be a domain on https).

3. Touch `#normalInput` (or any plain non credit-card text input) and the autofill is not visible as desired
4. Touch `#normalSelect` (or any non-credit card drop down on any) again and now autofill has gone

My question is, is there anything I can do (maybe apply something to select drop downs) to make sure it never offers credit card autofill?

Is this a known iOS bug?

I am using an iPhone6 iOS 8.1.2 Safari.

**EDITS**

1. Textareas also have this issue.
2. Adding `autocomplete="off"` does not prevent it.

Comment: Why you want to prevent credit card autofill? Security? Security of saved credit cards is the iOS is a system issue. You will make your site less usable, and nothing more.

Comment: I don't want to prevent it. I very much want it to offer credit card autofill on the right fields. However I want to prevent it offering to autofill credit card information on non credit card inputs. Especially as it seems to offer credit card autofill when you change to an insecure domain. It's obviously an iOS bug so I want to see if I can force a normal input to remove credit card autofill (that it should never have anyway).