# Credit Card autocomplete and scan on safari

Tags: html, autocomplete, safari, credit-card

After a bit of research I guess that autofill works (on safari) if input has specific id or name, see list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36151606/2366630

I tested each of them and it works perfect, but problem is that I can't change id or name attributes which are defined previously by my provider and they can't change server-side id or name.. also it doesn't match any from this list.

I also tried to change **type** and **class** attributes from this list but it doesn't work as well.

So my issue is next, beside id and name attributes how can I force input to work credit card autofill and scan function on safari..

This is what my input looks like:

```
<input id="cardn" name="cardn" type="text" autocomplete="cc-number" x-autocompletetype="cc-number" size="19" maxlength="19" class="form-input"  required="">
```