# How can I see whether the Scan Credit Card feature is working in safari in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, credit-card

I am trying to change a form that includes credit card input details so that when viewed on iOS it will give the user the option of scanning their credit card details (see below):

[image]

However, the solution I think should work (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163891/when-is-the-scan-credit-card-option-available-on-ios8-safari)) isn't showing the scan card option when I open the page in safari on XCode iOS Simulator so I want to know:

1. Should I expect the Simulator to work exactly like an actual device (I know some camera based things do not work)?
2. If so, what steps I need to take in order to get it working?
3. If not possible, what alternative routes might there be to testing whether the scan card feature is working for my form.

Comment: Since the simulator doesn't have a camera, I wouldn't expect that option to show. You will need to test on a real device.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - that makes sense to me and is pretty much what I expected unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The Simulator does not currently provide a virtual camera.

If this is something you'd like to see, please file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com and request camera support be added to the Simulator.